# Is this manipulation with logs allowed?

Tags: logarithms

$$\left( \frac{6}{7} \right) ^n < \frac{1}{65}$$
The answer is, by looking at which way the sign should be round:

$$n > \log_\frac{6}{7}{\left(\frac{1}{65}\right)} \implies n>\frac {\log{\frac{1}{65}}}{\log{\frac{6}{7}}}$$

However if I try to solve it by taking logs of both sides:
$$n\log{\frac{6}{7}} < \log{\frac{1}{65}}$$
When I divide by $\log{\frac{6}{7}}$ however, the sign switches only if it is less than $0$. Depending on the base of the log, the answer will either be (for example if the base is $\sqrt{\frac{6}{7}}$)...
$$n<\frac {\log{\frac{1}{65}}}{\log{\frac{6}{7}}}$$
Or...
$$n>\frac {\log{\frac{1}{65}}}{\log{\frac{6}{7}}}$$
...which is correct.
So what's wrong with my manipulation? Is there a formal way to show that the answer is indeed the second, by using the second method?

**Edit:**

I guess the main point of this question is to ask what is allowed when taking logs of both sides of an equation. I assumed these logs could be any base, but some bases seem to yield incorrect answers (for example what I wrote in the comments). Is there any way to formally show why this does not work?

Comment: You should keep in mind that $\log x<0$ if $x<1$. In you case, $\log\frac1{65}<0$ and also $\log\frac67<0$.

Comment: What's wrong with: $\log_{0.5}{0.25}=2$? @Tom-Tom

Comment: @Tom-Tom I mean, assuming the log can be any base (can't it?)...

Answer (score 3):

If you take $\log_a$, there are two possibilities.

If $a>1$ then $\log_a$ is increasing, and the direction of the inequality does not change.

If $0<a<1$, the function $\log_a$ is decreasing, and the direction of the inequality is reversed.

Comment: How about in the example: $$n\log_{0.5}{\frac{1}{4}}<\log_{0.5}{\frac{1}{16}}$$ Then $2n<4$ and $n<2$. No? @ajotatxe

Comment: I guess what I am asking is: why, when taking logs with bases less than 1, does the solution not work?

Comment: @bnosnehpets If $x<y$, then $\log_{0.5} x > \log_{0.5} y$. The step where you take logs of both sides and get $n\log_a{\frac{6}{7}} < \log_a{\frac{1}{65}}$ is correct only if $a > 1.$ That step is a mistake if $a=0.5$.

Comment: @David thanks that makes it clearer